# Azure Logic App - Am Unable to "create a SugarCRM Connector API" - not found in my view of the marketplace

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am just getting started with Azure Logic Apps and want to try connecting to SugarCRM.

I was pleased to see this guidance suggesting I should be able to find the SugarCRM connector in the Azure marketplace
https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-logic/app-service-logic-connector-sugarcrm.md
However, when I try to find it by going to the marketplace on portal.azure.com and searching for SugarCRM, I do not see the connector in the results as described in the above link.

Either it is no longer published or I am doing something wrong. Do I need to do anything special to be able to access this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check this on the portal I could find it, then I consult the Azure official. The response is

> SugarCRM was on product plan and later was removed.  So it was never formally released.

So this feature is not available, if you insist on using this you could go to feedback and vote up this feature. When there are enough people vote for it, there is more chance for it to be added. Here is the feedback link:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/20565706-add-sugarcrm

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, good to know I am not getting something fundamentally wrong.

Is there a way to use the stuff in the github file in any event?
Add it as a customet connector or something?
Work does seem to have been done

Comment: @ghm101,If this could help you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @ghm101, the work seems done is a preview version and now it's removed so this   mostly could not be achieved for now. About the custom connector you could have a try , I have not test it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will have to give the custom connector a try, I  had been hoping for a bit of plug and play, but oh well.(rolls up sleeves)